# Angularjs - Managing high volumes of html in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a ng-repeat that generates around 300 rows. I can't implement infinite scrolling since i need all the rows present on the page. For each row there are 3 elements.

When the page loads, i get all the rows from the database and if the element exists i display it, if not i have the option to add it by clicking on the place where the element would otherwise be. When clicked a form is displayed right under that element.

The form has 4 inputs, which is quite a lot of html. Now since we have two-way data binding, and we are inside the ng-repeat isolated scope, i can't use one form for all 3 elements (since the values in the inputs would be shared), i would need one for each. Considering the amount of rows, rendering so many forms takes more than i'd like.

To get a better idea of what i'm working with (visually, the code is not relevant anymore) http://plnkr.co/edit/xNYUbi?p=preview

I want to stick to the form dropdown under the add element option, so making a modal isn't an option.

How should i approach this problem?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly you are asking how you *should* write this, but ... at this point in time, are you having performance issues with ng-repeat?

Comment: Regardless of the answer to my question - have you looked at ng-grid?(http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/) Will it do anything like what you are looking for?

Comment: My problem is that loading the rows without the 3 forms in each list item takes 2 seconds, and with the forms 7 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain I understand the specific use case here so I will give some generic advice that I hope helps. When working with lots of data angular, there are a number of options:

- [ng-grid](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/): Has an edit mode and paging so with the correct settings you can pull down all your data, set the data source for the grid and the performance should still be pretty good.
- ng-repeat: If you have to have a custom U/I or you need additional functions in your U/I, ng-repeat is about as good as it gets. As long as you don't have nested repeats (can be bad) and you craft your UI carefully you should mostly be all right.
- Assuming that ng-repeat is still too slow you could think about implementing some form of paging or ng-infinite-scroll. With either option you can still load the entire data set initially and then display it in chunks rather than all at once.

At the end of the day - if the performance is unacceptable when you try to add all the elements to the DOM the only real solution is to alter the way those elements are added or simply don't add them at all (which is where all the above solutions really lead you). This might require talking to your client or going through a bit of re-design, but in the end it should be worth it. Best of luck!

Comment: So it comes down to making a trade-off, thanks. On this subject this article is worth a read as well http://tech.small-improvements.com/2013/09/10/angularjs-performance-with-large-lists/